Delaying opacification of Lemma in Coq
I am interested in ergonomic ways of expressing modal logic and relevant logics in Coq. I would prefer to do it without axioms (besides perhaps something like forall A, not (not A) -> A to make my environment classical).
Before work today I had an idea to use an opaque proof of $\text{Prop} \to \text{Prop}$ as a modal operator.
(* This is not really a lemma, I just want an opaque definition *)
Lemma necessarily : Prop -> Prop.
Proof. easy. Qed.

This gives me a propertyless modal operator $\square$ about which nothing is known.
If I want something extremely basic, like necessitation, I can introduce it with an axiom.
Axiom necessitation : forall A, necessarily A -> A.

However, this is unsatisfying to me because I could express $\text{necessitation}$ with an opaque definition if I could temporarily see the definition of $\text{necessarily}$ when defining $\text{necessitation}$.
The definition of necessarily, which is hidden away by using Qed. rather than Defined. is just $\text{id}_\text{Prop}$. This is a bona fide modal logic, namely one with modal collapse.
In the system with modal collapse, necessitation $\square A \to A$ is a tautology because $A \to A$ is a tautology.
Similarly, it would make sense to use $\to$ for relevant implication, since constructive implication is a degenerate form of relevant implication. This would provide a useful smoke check on whatever axioms I insist on later.
Lemma relevant_arrow : Prop -> Prop -> Prop. 
Proof. refine (fun A B => A -> B). Qed.                                                       
 
Infix "-->" := relevant_arrow (at level 41, right associativity).  

Anyway, OCaml, the implementation language of Coq has a module system which can be used to hide the definition of types and values.
module Foo : sig
  type t (* no one knows that t is an int *)
end = struct
  type t = int
end

Is it possible to do the same in Coq?

Coq has a module system too. Definitions are transparent inside a module, and opaque outside if the module is sealed by annotating it with a module type (Module Necessity : Modality.). (There is also a non-sealing annotation, Module Necessity <: Modality. which doesn't opacify its contents.)
Module Type Modality.
Parameter box : Prop -> Prop.
Parameter extract : forall P : Prop, box P -> P.
End Modality.

Module Necessity : Modality.
Definition box (P : Prop) := P.
Definition extract (P : Prop) (p : box P) := p.
End Necessity.

Import Necessity.

Lemma extract2 (P : Prop) : box (box P) -> P.
Proof.
  intros H.
  Fail apply H. (* box is opaque *)
  apply extract; apply extract; apply H.
Qed.

